# Class with std::map object and deleted copy assignment and constructor causes C2280 with std::pair's copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, dll

I'm trying to build my dll library after adding serialization classes to it. I have this code:

```
class VariablesSerializableValue
    : public SerializableValueBase
{
private:
    Serializable::Variables value;
public:
    VariablesSerializableValue() = default;
    VariablesSerializableValue(const VariablesSerializableValue&) = delete;

    VariablesSerializableValue(_In_ Serializable::Variables&& arg) noexcept;

    VariablesSerializableValue& operator=(const VariablesSerializableValue&) = delete;
    VariablesSerializableValue& operator=(_In_ Serializable::Variables&& arg) noexcept;

    const Serializable::Variables& getValue() const;

    void add(_In_ const String& name, _In_ UniquePtr<SerializableValueBase>&& arg);

    virtual UniquePtr<SerializableValueBase> clone() const override;
};
```

where SerializableValueBase is a polymorphic abstract class (code omitted, irrelevant).
Serializable::Variables is defined as follows:

```
class GLOWE_DLLEXPORT Serializable
{
public:
    using Variables = Map<String, UniquePtr<Hidden::SerializableValueBase>>;
    ...
```

`String` is a no-throw-movable string class, `UniquePtr` is just a template using of `std::unique_ptr`. `Map` is a template using of `std::map` with my own memory allocator supplied.

When I try to compile this code, I get `error C2280: 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair(const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`. The error log says that the error is caused by `Serializable::Variables value` declaration in `VariablesSerializableValue` class. I have no idea what causes this although I explicitly deleted copy constructor and assignment in the class.

I tried to convert this code so that it uses PIMPL, but it just moved the error to the .cpp file where the implementation class was declared and defined. I have no idea how to tackle this. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Show a [mcve] and a full and complete text of all error messages. Don't describe them in prose.

Comment: You should post a minima reproducible example. Without that, you will only get down-votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error with the std pair constructor is caused by a map operation that invokes the copy constructor, such as std::map::insert. A call to insert won't work, because one cannot copy a unique_ptr, so the compiler will complain about a deleted constructor. Instead, you will have to std::move the unique_ptr into the map when you call insert, or construct the pointer in place using std::map::emplace.

Hope that helps - if not, a small reproducible example is the way to go as others have said, I'm mostly guessing :)